# Can no longer run my ember app locally in Windows 7

Tags: ember.js, windows-7, ember-cli

I did my first development in a Win7 machine, then switched to a Mac when I got that, which was great due to the speed of building with `ember server` running. I've been keeping everything in a Git repo. Everything works fine running `ember server` from my Mac.

Now, when I do a fresh clone from the repo on my Win7 computer, then do `npm install` and `bower install` (both of which complete fine), when I run `ember server` next, I get a bunch of errors saying **ENOTEMPTY, directory not empty (path, blah blah blah)**.

It's complaining about some folder in the tmp directory, which the server command is creating and putting stuff into all by itself, so I don't know what it's complaining about.

I've been finagling with this about 5 different times now, but without success.
Ember CLI version is 0.1.1
Ember version is 1.6

Here's an example of one of the errors, but they're all similar (and similarly unhelpful):

```
ENOTEMPTY, directory not empty 'c:\Dev\star\tmp\remover-tmp_dest_dir-sRc08q1q.tm
p\templates'
Error: ENOTEMPTY, directory not empty 'c:\Dev\star\tmp\remover-tmp_dest_dir-sRc0
8q1q.tmp\templates'
    at Object.fs.rmdirSync (fs.js:623:18)
    at rmkidsSync (c:\Dev\star\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf
.js:247:11)
    at rmdirSync (c:\Dev\star\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.
js:237:7)
    at fixWinEPERMSync (c:\Dev\star\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\rimraf\r
imraf.js:150:5)
    at Function.rimrafSync [as sync] (c:\Dev\star\node_modules\ember-cli\node_mo
dules\rimraf\rimraf.js:216:26)
    at Remover._remove (c:\Dev\star\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\broccoli
-file-remover\index.js:46:10)
    at c:\Dev\star\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\broccoli-file-remover\ind
ex.js:60:14
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at c:\Dev\star\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\broccoli-file-remover\ind
ex.js:59:12
    at $$$internal$$tryCatch (c:\Dev\star\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\rs
vp\dist\rsvp.js:470:16)

file added bootstrap.min.js
file added favicon.ico
file added sb-admin-2.js
```

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I managed to do something that worked. I had forgotten I needed to disable Windows Indexing on my tmp folder at least (I did it for the whole cloned project):

1. Windows Key, type "Indexing Options"
2. Click the drive, then Modify
3. Uncheck places you don't want indexed (like the tmp folder)
4. If you use Sublime, go to Perferences --> Settings - User and add the following:
   "folder_exclude_patterns":
   [
       "tmp/*",
   ],

Finally, I just had to keep doing `ember server`, stopping it, and doing it again until it build successfully (took around 5 tries).